# For an older version of listing, how to find the number of customers? package requirements?

Tags: appexchange

I inherited a legacy codebase and am now trying to upgrade our AppExchange listing. I have two questions:

- How can I find out how many customers / which customers are on older versions of our listing?
- Is it possible to find out for an older package listing, what the package requirements were? I see when uploading my package to a "Managed - Beta" version that there are many package requirements. I am pretty sure we have none, but want to see what was listed in a prior release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find out how many customers / which customers are on older versions of our listing?

You do this from your LMO (License Management Org) via the LMA (License Management App). You want the Packages tab, select your package by name (note: the name can be outdated) then drill down via the Package Versions related list. The Licenses object is a child of Package Versions and gives you the subscriber details.

If your package is enabled for push upgrades, you can also get installed-org information via the push upgrades UI in the packaging org, but fair warning: it tends to be hard to interpret and may include orgs that aren't real, active customer orgs.

> Is it possible to find out for an older package listing, what the package requirements were? I see when uploading my package to a "Managed - Beta" version that there are many package requirements. I am pretty sure we have none, but want to see what was listed in a prior release.

I don't know of a way to do this, unfortunately (I'd love it if someone else knows!)

Note that the requirements shown on this screen are quite extensive and may include dependencies that you wouldn't think of as requirements, but which are in fact quite important - like Record Types, sharing on standard objects, and other facets of the org. These dependencies can be created by references in your code and metadata, including use of Chatter-related Quick Actions on Page Layouts, Apex references to the `RecordTypeId` field, and so on.